# Is there a way in Golang Generics to create something like "extends" in Typescript?

Tags: go, generics

I am trying to create a function using Go Generics that accepts any structs that meet minimum struct criteria. Something like `<T extends {name: string, age: number}>` in Typescript.

Here below is my function and I am trying to find a way to make it work. I would love to be able to pass any struct that has `Name string` and `Age int` to the `printNameAndAge` function because that function will be using only these two fields. Is this possible? I was not able to find an example or documentation for this use case?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Name   string
    Age    int
    Height float32
}

type Car struct {
    Age   int
    Name  string
    Model string
}

type NameAndAge struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}


func printNameAndAge[T (**missing extends or something like that**) NameAndAge](u T) {
    fmt.Println(u.Name)
    fmt.Println(u.Age)
}

func main() {
    newUser := User{
        Name:   "John",
        Age:    24,
        Height: 186,
    }
    newCar := Car{
        Name:  "Series 3",
        Age:   1,
        Model: "BMW",
    }

    printNameAndAge(newUser)
    printNameAndAge(newCar)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces.  Define interface with methods for common functionality. Implement those methods on each type.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Name   string
    Age    int
    Height float32
}

func (u User) getName() string { return u.Name }
func (u User) getAge() int     { return u.Age }

type Car struct {
    Age   int
    Name  string
    Model string
}

func (c Car) getName() string { return c.Name }
func (c Car) getAge() int     { return c.Age }

func printNameAndAge(x interface {
    getName() string
    getAge() int
}) {
    fmt.Println(x.getName())
    fmt.Println(x.getAge())
}

func main() {
    newUser := User{
        Name:   "John",
        Age:    24,
        Height: 186,
    }
    newCar := Car{
        Name:  "Series 3",
        Age:   1,
        Model: "BMW",
    }

    printNameAndAge(newUser)
    printNameAndAge(newCar)

}
```

Comment: don't you agree it would be easier if there was a way to let the function know it is a minimum type required instead of doing all this workaround staff?

Comment: Fields are not part of generics in 1.18, but that may change in a later release.

Comment: Here is a proposal: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51259

Answer (score -1):

You can try embed the substructure in your types like in the example below.

However the current solution is: *interfaces*

But hey thd type NameAndAge can have a method. And Car can expose this method via delegation.

```golang
type NameAndAge struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (na NameAndAge) Get()(string, int){
    return na.Name, na.Age
}

type Getter interface {
    Get()(string, int)
}

type Car struct {
    NameAndAge
    Model string
}

func Show(na NameAndAge) {
    fmt.Println(na.Name, na.Age)
}

func ShowInterface(g Getter){
    fmt.Println(g.Get())
}

func main() {
    var c Car
    c.Name = "Ford"
    c.Age = 40
    c.Model = "T"
    
    Show(c.NameAndAge)
    
    ShowInterface(c)

}
```